# Error in spring application context schema

Tags: spring, xsd, spring-data

I have a maven-spring project in Eclipse and I have this annoying error message in one of my spring contexts:

> Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/M2_HOME/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/
>    factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

The show setails leads to this:

[image]

I using spring-data-jpa 1.2.0.RELEASE and the rest of my spring jars are 3.1.3.RELEASE. Regarding spring-data-commons-core - I don't even have a dependency to this jar in my pom but I can see it in my m2 repository along with spring-data-commons-parent and both of version 1.4.0.RELEASE, I don't know why (maybe those are part of spring-data-jpa?).

My application context schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this error. Basically it has no effect what so ever, The app compiles, deployed and runs just fine, it is just this annoying red error mark in Eclipse that drives me crazy :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have solved it by doing 3 things:

1. Added this repository to my POM:

   ```
   <repository>
       <id>spring-milestone</id>
       <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
       <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
   </repository>
   ```
2. I'm using this version of spring-jpa:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. I removed the xsd versions from my context (although I'm not sure it is necessary):

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   > <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   >   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   >   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   >   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   >   xsi:schemaLocation="
   >    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   >    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   >    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   >    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
   >    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">
   > ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Dude works like a charm, also for mongodb! (with several tricks). I added it as a separate answer, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I recently had a similar problem in latest Eclipse (Kepler) and fixed it by disabling the option "Honour all XML schema locations" in Preferences > XML > XML Files > Validation.
It disables validation for references to the same namespaces that point to different schema locations, only taking the first found generally in the XML file being validated. This option comes from the Xerces library.

WTP Doc: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/releases/3.1.0/newandnoteworthy/sourceediting.php

Xerces Doc: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#honour-all-schemaLocations

Comment: works for Eclipse mars with Spring messed up project

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes the spring config xml file works not well on next eclipse open up.

It shows error in the xml file caused by schema definition, no matter reopen eclipse or clean up project are both not working.

But try this!

> Right click on the spring config xml file, and select `validate`.

After a while, the error disappears and eclipse tells you there is no error on this file.

What a joke...

Answer (score 8):

What I did with spring-data-jpa-1.3 was adding a version to xsd and lowered it to 1.2. Then the error message disappears. Like this

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        ...
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    ...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">
```

Seems like it was fixed for for 1.2 but then appears again in 1.3.

Answer (score 6):

I recently had same issue with Spring 4.0.

It was caused by a collision in names from `spring-beans-4.0.xsd` and `spring-context-4.0.xsd`.
Opening `spring-context-4.0.xsd` you can see that `spring-beans-4.0.xsd` is imported like follow:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd"/>
```

These name's collisions make Eclipse complain about "...A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name..."

A noteworthy aspect is that I hadn't this problem with Eclipse Kepler SR2 but Eclipse Luna SR1, comparing both preferences about XML Validation, they were the same.

**It was solved by removing spring-context-4.0.xsd from xsi:schemaLocation attribute:**

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
```

After this everything worked as expected.

Comment: But it would not solve problem if you are using 
<context:component-scan base-package="org.vimal.spring.service" /> I am yet to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have recently had same issue with JPA-1.3

Nothing worked until I used explicit tools.xsd link

```
xsi:schemaLocation=" ...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
    ... ">
```

like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
        ">
```

Comment: Same problem with Spring context 4.2. and solved it. Interestingly http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd links to the 4.1 spring tool

Comment: Thanks, Just adding the 2  schemaLocations works for me.       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool and 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have control those files, as those files can be part of other projects and you are not authorized to make any changes, then you can bypass those errors in eclipse by going, Preferences --> XML --> XML Files --> Validation --> Referenced file contains errors --> choose Ignore option.

And let project get's validated, the error message will disappear.

Answer (score 3):

What @forhas and @HRgiger did also worked for me. I am using `spring-data-mongodb` instead of `jpa`.

However, for mongodb bindings, you should not remove the version of mongodb reference xsd, just keep it with version: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd`. `context` and `beans` versions should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I removed this error by updating the version number in

```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
```

to 4.3 as I had upadated spring version in pom as 4.3.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and fixed it by removing version part from the XSD name.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd to http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
```

Versions less XSD's are mapped to the current version of the framework used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Referenced file contains errors
>   (http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd)

i faced this problem, when i was configuring dispatcher-servlet.xml ,you can remove this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
```

from your xml and you can also follow the steps 
go to window -> preferences -> validation -> and unchecked XML validator and XML schema validator.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to resolve this issue
1.Right click on your project
2.Click on validate option

Result :TODO issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd"
```

Answer (score 0):

add this xml config file. It's no show error.

```
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd
```

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar files have been properly added then go [here](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/6850606) for the rest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This happen to me after upgrade eclipse version. What works for me was clean the eclipse cache. Go to Window > Preferences > Network Connection > Cache > Remove All.

I hope this works for anyone!