# Spring-Data-JPA causes XSD validation error in Spring STS using XML configuration

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Eclipse/STS reports errors using Spring 3.2.1 with Spring-data-jpa together.
I have some XML configuration files with the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
```

I am using Spring 3.2.1 with Spring-Data-JPA 1.3.0 and Eclipse/STS is reporting this:

> Referenced file contains errors
>   (http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa)

This happens in every single XML configuration file that contains the data-jpa schema.
When I remove JPA from the XML config, everything is just fine.

Is my configuration wrong or what happens here?

Thanks!
Paul

Comment: I get the same thing. I suspect it's because spring 3.2 dependencies import spring-tool-3.2 and spring data xsd imports spring-tool.xsd (no 3.2 suffix). Still don't know how to fix it though

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693065/error-in-spring-application-context-schema

Answer (score 7):

Today there is not a http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xml file so you have to use http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd, but this file use http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd that does not exist too so you have to add the location of this schema in your context file:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd"
```

Comment: I just came across this problem. Thanks for sharing!