# Spring-intergration-ftp, i am getting error ....ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd contains errors

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I am trying to send the file to remote directory using ftp-outbound-channel-adapter in spring integration.  I am getting the xsd error as "Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd)".

i am using 4.3.5.RELEASE.  I couldnt format xml here.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd">
```

any suggestions?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, share Stack Trace on the matter and some config to determine the cause. Also, confirm, please, that it is at runtime, not your IDE issue.

Comment: Also, it does appear like an IDE issue. If so (and I've experienced it before multiple times), may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693065/error-in-spring-application-context-schema. Basically it may be as simple as disabling certain XSD validation.

Comment: Or use a spring-aware IDE (e.g. STS) which knows how to find the proper schema on the classpath.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, it's not run time issue. i am using eclipse kepler. I will try in STS,  i see the following info in problem section ` src-resolve: cannot resolve the name    'integration:smartLifeCycleAttributeGroup' to a(n) 'attributegroup'  component.s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: the contentof'base-adapter-type' is invalid. src-resolve-cannot resolve the name 'int-file:remoteOutboundattributegroup'to a(n) 'attributegroup' component`

Comment: Right, you have to turn on somehow Spring nature in your Eclipse to let it to scan for XSDs in the classpath.

Comment: got resolved in STS, thank you guys.